# Detecting If The Correct USB Device Is Connected - Swift

Tags: swift, macos, usb, iokit

Using the latest SwiftUI and XCode 13, with a target of OS 12.3+ I need to detect whether or not a specific USB drive is connected to the machine. If it is I need to set a variable to true, if it's removed set that var to false.

I have yet to find any sort of updated code examples to do this, and Apple's docs are, well... Apple's docs.

I have it working with the following code, which prints info to the console. It only looks for USB devices with the VolumeUUID specified, but as it's really old C code, I'm hoping someone can share a much more updated way of doing this, which will also allow me to set a variable instead of just printing to the console.

```
import DiskArbitration
import Foundation
import IOKit

class USB_Helper: ObservableObject {

    @Published var usbConnected: Bool = false

    init() {
        print("USB Helper Initialized")
        tryUSB()
    }

    func tryUSB() {
        let validation: CFDictionary = [
            "DADeviceProtocol":"USB",
            "DAVolumeUUID": CFUUIDCreateFromString(kCFAllocatorDefault, "F0672BD0-1FA9-3567-452F-322138E12C35" as CFString)!
        ] as CFDictionary

        let diskAppearedCallback: DADiskAppearedCallback = {
            disk,
            context in print(
                "Disk appeared:",
                disk
            )
            printDiskInfo(
                disk
            )
        }

        let diskDisappearedCallback: DADiskDisappearedCallback = {
            disk,
            context in print(
                "Disk disappeared:",
                disk
            )
            printDiskInfo(
                disk
            )
        }

        let runloop = RunLoop.current
        let session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault)!

        func printDiskInfo(_ disk: DADisk) {
            guard let description = DADiskCopyDescription(disk) as? [String: Any] else {
                fatalError()
            }
            print(description)
        }

        DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(
            session,
            validation,
            diskAppearedCallback,
            nil
        )

        DARegisterDiskDisappearedCallback(
            session,
            validation,
            diskDisappearedCallback,
            nil
        )

        DASessionScheduleWithRunLoop(
            session,
            runloop.getCFRunLoop(),
            CFRunLoopMode.defaultMode.rawValue
        )

    } // End Func

} // End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that there seems to be no way to set the variable from within the callback, however the solution is rather simple.

1. You want to send out a notification
2. You want to catch that notification and run a function that resides outside of the tryUSB function to set the bool variable

Here are the functions to set the variable:

```
@objc func usbTrue() {
    self.usbConnected = true
    print("USB Connected")
}

@objc func usbFalse() {
    self.usbConnected = false
    print("USB Disconnected")
}
```

Here are the modifications to the callbacks with the notifications:

```
let diskAppearedCallback: DADiskAppearedCallback = {
            disk,
            context in print(
                "Disk appeared:",
                disk
            )
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("DiskAppeared"), object: disk)
        }

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(usbTrue), name: Notification.Name("DiskAppeared"), object: nil)

        let diskDisappearedCallback: DADiskDisappearedCallback = {
            disk,
            context in print(
                "Disk disappeared:",
                disk
            )
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("DiskDisappeared"), object: disk)
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(usbFalse), name: Notification.Name("DiskDisappeared"), object: nil)
```

I really hope this post helps others because it took me a long time to figure it out. Good luck!